# C# stored procedure error db parameter expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a stored procedure which inserts data from a web form to a table in my database.

During the execution an error popped up such as "Procedure or function 'getpopteam' expects parameter '@tname', which was not supplied", but when I entered into the my table in the db, all the values inserted in the web form is present in the db.

I executed it again and above mentioned error popped up again and all the values are successfully inserted into the database. I don't know what the problem is.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and SQL Server 2008

```
datacon();

con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("getpopteam", con);

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("tname", txtteamname.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("usermail", txtemails.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("userpwd", txtpasswords.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("usercountry", countrydd.SelectedValue));
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

con.Close();
```

Comment: Unless you can provide some details we can't help. All you have said is "my code has an error". I assume you have a procedure or function called "getpopteam" and it has some parameters. I suspect you are not passing it a value for @tname.

Comment: It wants a parameter called `@tname`, not one called `tname`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of typing string value of "tname", try prepending with the "@" symbol instead like this...

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tname", txtteamname.Text))
```

Hope this helps.